# URL rewriting- How can I turn example.com/pageid.php?id=12 to example.com/full-title

Tags: php, url-rewriting, apache2

I want to make my pages search engine friendly and it also looks better that ***example.com/pageid.php?id=12***

I have pages different pages like *showUser.php* *showLocation.php* and I want all these to be rewritten.

Wo'nt mod_rewrite slow down my app a little bit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your particular example, `mod_rewrite` could be set up something like this:

```
# .htaccess
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/([\w-]+)$ /page.php?title=$1
```

Now, a request to `/full-title` would resolve to `page.php` and `$_GET['title']` would hold the value `'full-title'`.

(Most web frameworks (such as Symfony, Django etc.) allow for customizable URL routing rules which do not require you to hardcode rewrite rules in your `.htaccess` file.)

Answer (score 3):

You need to take a look at mod_rewrite (providing your host supports it) - here's [a good blog post on the subject](http://www.workingwith.me.uk/articles/scripting/mod_rewrite).

Comment: Mod rewrite is the way to go if your using Apache. Don't know how to do it on IIS, at least not for free.

Comment: would'nt mod_rewrite slow down my app a little bit?

Comment: @Smitch325 This one http://iis.net/extensions/URLRewrite is free, at least. Have not tested it, though.
@Ankit Unless you have a zillion rewrite rules, the overhead of using mod_rewrite is pretty negligible. I wouldn't worry about it.